# Unsubscribe Apache pulsar shared subscription type

Tags: java, failover, apache-pulsar

I am trying to run Apache pulsar client with multiple consumers on a subscription in Shared mode. This multiple consumers are running in multiple threads.
But on trying to unsubscribe the consumer getting error message as
"Unconnected or shared consumer attempting to unsubscribe".

cant we unsubscribe shared subscription. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to unsubscribe, you generally need to first disconnect all the other consumers.

If there are other consumers connected, they will just reconnect and re-create the subscription.